# Binding a command to an 'LostMouseCapture' event of xctk:IntegerUpDown

Tags: wpf, events, mvvm, data-binding, command

I want to bind a Icommand to an event of xctk:IntegerUpDown. Event is 'LostMouseCapture'

In XAML:

```
<xctk:IntegerUpDown Name="MinColor" ClipValueToMinMax="True" Grid.Column="2" 
                                                    Minimum="0" Maximum="{Binding Path=MinColorMaxValue}" Value="{Binding Path=MinColorValue}" Increment="1"   
                                                    PreviewTextInput="IntegerUpDown_PreviewTextInput" DataObject.Pasting="IntegerUpDown_Pasting" PreviewKeyDown="IntegerUpDown_PreviewKeyDown" >
                                                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostMouseCapture">
                                                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=ValueCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding FileName}"/>
                                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                                </xctk:IntegerUpDown>
```

In ViewModel :

```
private DelegateCommand m_ValueCommand = null;          

    public ICommand ValueCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_ValueCommand == null)
                m_ValueCommand = new DelegateCommand(new Action<object>(ExecuteValueCommand),
                    new Predicate<object>(CanExecuteValueCommand));
            return m_ValueCommand;
        }
    }

    public bool CanExecuteValueCommand(object sender)
    {  
        return true;
    }

    public void ExecuteValueCommand(object sender)
    {
    }
```

When I put some value in IntegerUpdown and click outside, then I want to call 'ValueCommand'. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your command from the setter of your `MinColorValue` source property:

```
private int _minColorValue;
public int MinColorValue
{
    get { return _minColorValue; }
    set
    {
        _minColorValue = value;
        ValueCommand.Execute(FileName);
    }
}
```

Or try to handle the `LostKeyboardFocus` or `LostFocus` event:

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="LostKeyboardFocus">
```